# Python - Pandas Insert Column in Dataframe Once

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm writing a Python program to lookup the MX record of a list of domains and spit it out to an CSV file. So far everything is working but I'm running into one small issue I can't seem to get across.

Here is my code:

```
import dns.resolver
import pandas as pd

mx = []
domans = []
provider = pd.Series([])
domain = input("Domain Name\n")
result = dns.resolver.resolve(domain, 'MX')
for exdata in result:
  exdata = str(exdata)
  exdata = exdata.split(" ")
  mx.append(exdata[1])

domain = domain + ","
num_domains = domain * len(mx)
num_domains = str(num_domains)
num_domains = num_domains.split(",")

for g in num_domains:
  g = str(g)
  g = g.split(",")
  domans.append(g[0])

if any("mail.protection.outlook.com" in x for x in exdata):
  provider = "Office 365"
elif any("google" in x for x in exdata):
  provider = "Google"
elif any("mimecast" in x for x in exdata):
  provider = "Mimecast"

dataset = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(domans, mx)))
dataset.insert(2, "Provider", provider) 
dataset.sample(0)
dataset.columns = ['domain','mx record','Provider']
dataset.dropna(axis = 0, how = 'any', inplace = True)
dataset.index = pd.RangeIndex(len(dataset.index))

dataset.to_csv (r'export_dataframe.csv', index = False, header=True)
```

Here is the CSV result when the input is google.com

```
domain,mx record,Provider
google.com,alt3.aspmx.l.google.com.,Google
google.com,alt1.aspmx.l.google.com.,Google
google.com,alt2.aspmx.l.google.com.,Google
google.com,alt4.aspmx.l.google.com.,Google
google.com,aspmx.l.google.com.,Google
```

All I want is for the Provider to only print "google" one time. This way I can look at the CSV list and capture an accurate number of providers.

Any input is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what output you are expecting, but it is possible using Groupby to make it a single line while keeping the MX records.

```
df = df.groupby(['Provider','domain'])['mx record'].agg(list)
df.to_csv (r'export_dataframe.csv', index=True, header=True)
```

export_dataframe.csv

```
Provider,domain,mx record
Google,google.com,"['alt3.aspmx.l.google.com.', 'alt1.aspmx.l.google.com.', 'alt2.aspmx.l.google.com.', 'alt4.aspmx.l.google.com.', 'aspmx.l.google.com.']"
```